# i am using jquery vertical accordion menu. after login my first page load. how to highlight that my first page

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

i am using jquery vertical accordion menu. after login, my first page is load. how to highlight that my first page. By default iam using jquery click events for highlight.

Comment: What you have tried? And please clarify your problem clearly....

Comment: in asp.net i am using jquery vertical accordion. ex. menu1,menu2,menu3........ now i clicked menu 2 that highlighted. then logout the page. then login the page, now the previous clicked menu2 highlighted is now also maintained. i want refresh the menu while login.... thanks for your reply

Comment: what do u mean by highlight? Do you want to open the first accordion after login and highlight it?

Comment: yes.. i want to highlight first page

Comment: see my answer and try it. for more details on accordion see: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Answer (score 1):

As you do not mention your code so i am assuming and giving you example:

```
Initialize the accordion with the active option specified:

$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });

Get or set the active option, after initialization:
// getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Change the value where 2 is mention. Mention the accordion value which you want to open after login.

Comment: if this answer is suitable for your need and correct then accept it that is the stackoverflow rule.